# login via google client->authenticate problem

Tags: php, authentication, google-signin

EDIT : SOLVED
changed 67 row for this

if (($this->handles ? count($this->handles) : 0) >= $this->maxHandles) {

Hi if i keep this line of code:

$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);

the error occur.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpZadanie1\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:67 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\phpZadanie1\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(67): count(NULL) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\phpZadanie1\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(107): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory->release(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle)) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\phpZadanie1\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlHandler.php(43): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\phpZadanie1\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\Proxy.php(28): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\phpZadanie1\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\Proxy.php(51): GuzzleHttp\Handler\Proxy::GuzzleHttp\Handler\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\phpZadanie1\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\PrepareBodyMiddleware.php(72): GuzzleHttp\Handler\Proxy::GuzzleHttp\Handler\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\phpZadanie1\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Middleware.php(30): GuzzleHttp\PrepareBodyMiddleware->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\phpZadanie1\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\RedirectMiddleware.php(68): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\phpZadanie1\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Middleware.php(57): GuzzleHttp\RedirectMiddleware->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\phpZadanie1\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\HandlerStack.php(67): GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp\{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) #10 C:\xampp\htdocs\phpZadanie1\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php(268): GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\phpZadanie1\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php(96): GuzzleHttp\Client->transfer(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\phpZadanie1\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Client.php(104): GuzzleHttp\Client->sendAsync(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) #13 C:\xampp\htdocs\phpZadanie1\vendor\google\auth\src\HttpHandler\Guzzle6HttpHandler.php(34): GuzzleHttp\Client->send(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Array) #14 C:\xampp\htdocs\phpZadanie1\vendor\google\auth\src\OAuth2.php(492): Google\Auth\HttpHandler\Guzzle6HttpHandler->__invoke(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request)) #15 C:\xampp\htdocs\phpZadanie1\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php(184): Google\Auth\OAuth2->fetchAuthToken(Object(Google\Auth\HttpHandler\Guzzle6HttpHandler)) #16 C:\xampp\htdocs\phpZadanie1\vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Client.php(163): Google_Client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode('4/0AWtgzh41sv8F...') #17 C:\xampp\htdocs\phpZadanie1\index.php(43): Google_Client->authenticate('4/0AWtgzh41sv8F...') #18 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpZadanie1\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 67
```

in basic code:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$clientID = 'myid';
$clientSecret = 'mysecret';
$redirectUri = 'mysite';


$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($clientID);
$client->setClientSecret($clientSecret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirectUri);
$client->addScope("email");
$client->addScope("profile");

// Create a new Google_Service_Oauth2 object
$service = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);

// If the user has clicked the "Sign in with Google" button
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']); // Exchange authorization code for access token
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken(); // Store the access token in the session
  header('Location: hlupost.php'); // Redirect back to the original page
}

// If the access token is already stored in the session
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
  $userInfo = $service->userinfo->get(); // Get the user's basic profile information

  echo "<p>Welcome, " . $userInfo['given_name'] . "!</p>";
  echo "<p>Your email address is: " . $userInfo['email'] . "</p>";
  echo "<p>Your Google ID is: " . $userInfo['id'] . "</p>";
} else {
  // Generate a URL to request access from the user
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
  echo "<a href='$authUrl'>Sign in with Google</a>";
}
```

Im noob at this so how can i fix it withou destroying whole libary
Also im not sure if it is how it should be, but after one log in with google, browser doesn't ask for another google mail and password even after restating pc it just redirect me immediately. if it is correct is there way to force google login window after revisiting page?

Thank you very much.

i tried changing id and secret. updating liberties with composer.

Comment: Are you sure $_GET['code'] is what you expect? Have you verified the data?

Comment: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#authentication-with-oauth (I think that is what you are using?) shows `$token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);` as the correct way to exchange the code for a token.

Comment: _"but after one log in with google, browser doesn't ask for another google mail and password even after restating pc it just redirect me immediately"_ - yes, that is how it is supposed to work. Users are not supposed to be bothered with granting the same permissions again, if they already did so previously. Various OAUth providers might provide additional parameters to "force" a re-entry of the user password at least, you'd have to check the individual provider's documentation.

Comment: '$token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);' shows the same error  
i got this code from chatGPT as basic example of google login whitch is shown on lot of pages whitch suggets how to implement google login so it should work